# funding for current Master's students in the USA

Tags: masters, application, funding, united-states

If one didn't obtain any funding before being admitted into a Master's program, is it hard to find funding in the middle of the Master's? Are RAs and TAs strictly reserved of PhDs? Any funding other than RAs and TAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many (I daresay *most*) departments, funding for Masters students is fairly hard to come by, especially for students in Masters-specific programs (rather than students who are in programs that are expected to roll into a PhD).

There are a number of reasons for this, ranging from Masters students being unlikely to produce much in an RA position before they move on to Masters students actively being used as an source of income for the department (this is especially common for professional-type Masters programs).

It may still be possible to find funding - I occasionally hire Masters students for short term projects etc. but it's definitely more difficult.

Comment: @ Fomite i have no personal experience applying for an RA. let's say i'm doing a MS, but if i (with PhD in another field) go to my PhD department for an RA, will professors b happier to offer me an RA, as i have very strong track record in that field?

Comment: @feynman Maybe? Though given you're no longer a student *in* said department, there are incentives against that as well.

Comment: @ Fomite i mean i go to the department in my new school. but this department is in the same discipline of my phd

Comment: @feynman Same problem - you’re not going to be around long, and they need that support for their students